# PHP calculation not adding up correctly

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

There is a total price displayed on my page however something is making this display incorrectly. I am not sure what is causing the price to calculate wrong, but I would like to know how I can solve this.

Here is my code:

```
function cart() {
$total=0;

$output = '';
$output .= '<center>';
$output .= '<table class="menufinal" border=0 width=75%>';
$output .= '<tr>';
$output .= '<th>Remove Item</th>';
$output .= '<th>Item Name</th>';
$output .= '<th>Item Price</th>';
$output .= '<th>Quantity</th>';
$output .= '<th>Line Total</th>';
$output .= '</tr>';

foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value) {
    if ($value>0){
        if (substr($name, 0, 5)=='cart_') {
           $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen($name)-5));
           $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, price FROM products WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id));
           while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)) {
                $sub = $get_row['price']*$value;
                $output .= '<tr>';
                $output .= '<td><a href="cart.php?delete=' .$id.'"><img src="x.png"></a><br></td>';
                $output .= '<td>' . $get_row['name'] . '</td>';
                $output .= '<td>&pound ' . number_format($get_row['price'], 2) . '</td>';
                $output .= '<td><a href="cart.php?remove=' .$id. '"style="text-decoration:none"><strong>- </strong></a>' .$value. '<a href="cart.php?add=' .$id. '"style="text-decoration:none"> +</a></td>';
                $output .= '<td>&pound ' . number_format($sub, 2) . '</td>';
                $output .= '</tr>';
            }
        } 
        if (empty($total)) {

            if (empty($sub)) {
                //do nothing
            } else {
                $total = $sub;
            }
        } else {
            $total += $sub;
        }
        $_SESSION['total'] = $total;
    }
}

$output .= '</table>';

if (empty($total)){
    session_destroy();
    header ('Location: index.php');
    exit;    
}

$output .=  '<br><br><br><br><div id="finalPrice">Total: &pound ' . number_format($total, 2) . '<br></div>';
$output .=  '<br><br><br><p><a href="index.php"><img src="dishes.png" width="240" height="152"></a> <img src="spacer.png" width="110"> <a href="checkout.php"><img src="checkout.png" width="240" height="151"></a>';

echo $output;
}
```

Comment: Adding should be done inside `while` loop I think, and init `$total` with 0.

Comment: just write these after while loop `$sub = $get_row['price']*$value; $total+=$sub;` no need your `if (empty($total))..these if else statement.

Comment: could you illustrate the data source for your while, and expecting values before the loop and after. and exact real output now what you think are wrong or unexpected that would help us to understand your issue better